# Problem with wireless driver on ubuntu 15.04 and lenovo z51-70

Tags: 15.04, lenovo

I have installed ubuntu 15.04 along with windows 10 dual boot.Wireless is not working properly in ubuntu.Its not listing the networks.
On the other hand in windows its working absolutely fine.
Please suggest which driver is needed to make wifi work on ubuntu.

Output of -- lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
   Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X] [1002:6820] (rev 81)     Above is the outpute for the comand

Comment: This adapter is not supported yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 that means I have to use an external WiFi adapter.

Comment: @Pilot6: could you convert last comment above this on to an answer?

Comment: You could try to install the latest firmware(updated just 3 days ago) from here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/firmware

Comment: I will try n share.

Comment: @Fabby I gave this answer for this adapter once or twice, but I can't find duplicates.

Comment: @Anurag ath10k does not support it yet. But I am sure it will soon.

Comment: ok I am just installing it and checking.....if nothing works i will use a wireless adapter

Comment: @Yalokly it updated the firmware its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu14.04.3 on lennovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)

Comment: @Pilot6 dude u marked this as duplicate I asked this question on 16th Aug and the question you marked was asked on 25th Sep.How this can be a duplicate.

Comment: It does not matter much when the question was answered. But I marked it as a duplicate of the question with the working solution.

Comment: ohh great thanks. I fixed this issue with bellow answer mentioned by  @5ud0 so i accepted that answer. Thanks Pilot6 for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to get your WIFI.
Prior to this update your kernel by installing from this page

> http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

I installed 4.0.0 since latest 4.2 crashes my bluetooth and then follow the steps from here :

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940/comments/34

Comment: It did'nt work..

Comment: Are you sure.Mine is the same laptop!

Comment: Did u install the kernel and followed the steps exactly?

and also added the line to modprobe?

Comment: Yaa i tried with both the kernel's 4.2 and 4.0 with both its not working ..

Comment: Sorry dude,Me and my friends got the same laptop Lenovo Z51-70.

One difference from yours is we installed Ubuntu 14.04 or elementary freya(my recommendation ;) ).May be you might have luck with that

Comment: Thanks, But i can't downgrade now.I have to take backup and I will try this weekend.For now I am using external usb wifi.

Comment: It worked for me thanks @5ud0. I downgraded to 4.0 and it works fine.

Comment: getting error `modprobe: Error: could not insert 'ath10k_pci' : Required key not available` for lenovo Z51 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for Ubuntu 15.4
I worked on the answer given by [5ud0](https://askubuntu.com/users/443964/5ud0) and made it work up here.
Just to make everyone's life easy here is the [zip file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8fX5_jSc475LWFhSUJPbk9SUFU/view?usp=sharing)
It has a patched code and the instructions
Hope it helps
This was put together by one of my colleague in office.